# Posts not displayed in order

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, cocoa-touch, parse-platform

I am working on an app that allows users to post into the main timeline. 
I am using Parse Framework, and I am using an array to post on a TableView.

This is the code I have been using so that the posts are displayed by newest to oldest:

```
 @IBAction func loadData() {
    timelineData.removeAllObjects()

    var findTimelineData:PFQuery = PFQuery(className: "Posts")

    findTimelineData.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock{
        (objects: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

        if error == nil{
            for object in objects!{
                let post:PFObject = object as! PFObject
                self.timelineData.addObject(post)
            }

            let array:NSArray = self.timelineData.reverseObjectEnumerator().allObjects
            self.timelineData = NSMutableArray(array: array)

            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }
}
```

It was working fine since I wrote it, and it's been a few days, until today, the posts aren't posting from newest to oldest, but more like in a random order:

[image: Random oder posts]

You can check the time posted in the photo, and the order is all random.

So I was wondering, is there another way to reverse the order of the array? or what is it affecting the order of the posts? or is it maybe the Parse framework that is not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't told Parse to use a certain order so add this after creating PFQuery:

```
findTimelineData.orderByDescending("createdAt")
```

Comment: `findTimelineData.orderByAscending("createdAt")` I used ascending so it shows the newest first. But this worked just fine. Once again, thank you. I was stuck here for hours and I couldn't figure it out. Until I finally gave in, and asked here.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem for a long time. Use a dictionary instead of an array and that will fix it.

Comment: That's not the problem. He needs it in an array to use it. An array does have a set order, he just needs it to be reordered.

Comment: Ah yes, if the elements inside the cells are correct than the array is fine. If it's just the order of cells then yes, you are correct. Thanks for catching that.

Comment: Yes I needed the array to have a set order. The answer @kdogisthebest worked for me (: